# Does an Indian citizen need a transit visa in Australia?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, australia, transit-visas

Indian passport holder. Do I need transit visa in Sydney?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are an Indian passport holder then you do need to apply for a transit visa. You can [fill out the forms provided here](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771) and hand them in at an Australian Visa Office in your country.

Comment: Note, for applicants in Tokyo, please send it directly to Seoul office, Tokyo office has no such services. ref: http://japan.embassy.gov.au/tkyo/subclass771.html

more detailed document: https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/771-

Answer (score -1):

YES.you should take transit visa before you travel.

The following categories of travellers are eligible to transit through Australia
without applying for a visa if they also meet the criteria below:
Citizens of the following countries:
Andorra, Argentina, Austria, Belgium, Brunei, Bulgaria, Canada, Chile,
Croatia, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia, Federated States of
Micronesia, Fiji, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland,
Indonesia, Ireland, Italy, Japan, Kiribati, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania,
Luxembourg, Malaysia, Malta, Marshall Islands, Mexico, Monaco, Nauru,
Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Oman, Palau, Papua New Guinea,
Philippines, Poland, Portugal, Qatar, Romania, Samoa, San Marino,
Singapore, Slovakia, Slovenia, Solomon Islands, South Africa, South
Korea, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, Thailand, Tonga, Tuvalu, United Arab
Emirates, United Kingdom (including its colonies), United States of
America, Uruguay, Vanuatu and Vatican.
Residents of Hong Kong holding a Hong Kong Special Administrative
Region (HKSAR) passport or a British National Overseas (BNO) passport.
Residents of Taiwan holding a passport issued by the authorities of
Taiwan (other than passports purported to be ocial or diplomatic
passports).
(Unfortunately India Not listed)