# Auckland to New delhi (India) with a stop at sydney for 72 hours- Australian visa required?

Tags: visas, air-travel, australia

I am going back to India from Auckland, I wish to make a halt of 72 hours to visit my cousin at Sydney. I don't have any visa for Australia.
What is required for this stop over?

Comment: Related: [Does an Indian citizen need a transit visa in Australia?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23802/does-an-indian-citizen-need-a-transit-visa-in-australia) - You need some sort of visa whether entering the country or not

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply for a transit visa (my emphasis):

> The Transit visa (subclass 771) lets you transit through Australia for
>   **no longer than 72 hours** if either:
>
> - you need to pass through Australia on your way to another country or
> - you need to pass through Australia to join a ship as a member of the crew.
>
> You can include dependent children on your visa application if they
>   are travelling with you on your passport.

You can find out all the information [at this website](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/771-) of the Australian Government's Department of Immigration and Border Protection.

Comment: For a 72 hour visit, is that still a transit visa, or is that a normal visitors visa?

Comment: The transit visa is for **upto 72 hours**.

Comment: Objectively, the law means the transit time being 72:00 you need a transit visa, and for 72:01 and above you need a regular visa. This implies that if it says on your ticket that your flight is going to arrive on Tuesday at 13:00 and the next one will depart on Friday at exactly 13:00, you can apply for a transit visa, but not anymore if the flight departure is stated to be at 13:01. How they would apply the rules at the border control is a completely different question.